# Firebase Storage returning SignatureDoesNotMatch on accessing uploaded link

Tags: firebase, file-upload, google-cloud-storage, access-token

I have uploaded some documents to google cloud storage and stored the returned signed URL in the database. Later we found that some URL seems to be corrupted and shows the following error when we try to open the link.

```html
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Message>
<StringToSign>GET 1675296000 /projectt2.com/user%2FQf%2Finferences%767876%2FReport</StringToSign>
</Error>
```

Also, we have identified that some of the documents will not have any access token in the firebase storage but the others which are valid will have the same. Both these files are created from the same source code. *(There are other documents that are of other modules which we can view even without access token)*

Here is the code snippet for converting the file

```
 const pdf = await request
                      .get({
                            uri: document.filePath,
                            encoding: null,
                            headers: {
                                      "Content-type": (document?.filePath?.toUpperCase().includes('PDF')) ? "text/pdf" : "image/jpeg",
                                     }
                                });
 const mime_type = (document?.filePath?.toUpperCase().includes('PDF')) ? 'application/pdf' : 'image/jpeg'
 const imageData = await addFileToStorage(pdf, `user/${uid}/inferences/${inference_id}/${document.specifiedType}`, mime_type, 365)
 const urls = await imageData.url;
 return {
           type: document.specifiedType,
           url: urls?.length ? urls[0] : '',
           path: (imageData) ? imageData.path : ''
         }
```

Code for Cloud storage file upload `addFileToStorage`

```
import {config} from "firebase-functions";
import {storage} from "../../config/config";
import * as moment from "moment-timezone";

export const bucket = storage.bucket(config().google.storage_url);

export const addFileToStorage = (data: any, path: string, mime_type: string, expiry: number = 1) => {
    const currentDate = new Date();
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + expiry);
    const expiryDate = moment.tz(currentDate, 'Europe/London').format('MM-DD-YYYY');

    const file = bucket.file(path);
    const fileOptions = {contentType: mime_type};
    return file.save(data, fileOptions)
        .then(() => {
            return {
                url: file.getSignedUrl({action: 'read', expires: expiryDate}),
                path
            }
        });
}
```

I am not sure is that the issue related to uploading or anything related to storage url.

Comment: Have you tried the solution [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/issues/1976#issuecomment-278762945), where they removed the content type while creating the signed URL? Also, you can check if there may be special characters in the file name which is a limitation at the moment.

Comment: @MabelA. I have tried removing the content type and the document is uploading correctly. But, on viewing the URL it seems to be downloading instead of viewing on the browser.